# Do laptops use different batteries than powerbanks

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

So I was researching about laptop batteries and I got confused on whether laptop batteries and other batteries like power banks are the same. To clarify I was looking at the new MacBook Pro battery specs and it has a 100wh battery capacity which is around 8,800 mAh, when looking around the web there are other batteries like power banks with 10,000 mAh, 20,000mAh, etc but with a much less price tag. So to come to my question. Are the batteries inside laptops the same as the power banks? And if so, question 1, why are big-name laptop batteries priced (800% +) above the power bank prices with the same capacity (ignoring the fact that they are manufactured by big-names). And question 2, why don't they use bigger say 20,000mAh for more device uptime because power banks come with that capacity? Any help on clarifying this would help. Thanks in advance.

**JUST FOR REFERENCE OF PRICE DIFFERENCE:**

https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Battery-Banks-Wholesale-USB-Portable-Battery_62451720213.html?spm=a2700.galleryofferlist.normal_offer.d_title.19377cacADgTTO&s=p

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/denaq-lithium-ion-battery-for-apple-macbook-pro-with-retina-display-laptops/6382319.p?skuId=6382319&ref=212&loc=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAqbyNBhC2ARIsALDwAsB4ZUaWkaVxfURrbrYrvA7RC1IBEM50EfFNOY4E1qA1pPG-ftbmolsaAoMVEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Traditionally yes, currently no.

Comment: in what way did they change @Andyaka

Comment: Anything you get off alibaba is going to be cheaper than an equivalent thing from a reputable manufacturer, and with batteries in particular probably not have anywhere near its actual rated capacity. For reference, a single 18650 (the type of cell most commonly used in power banks) is with current technology limited to somewhere around 3000 or 3500 mAh, but you'll see ones from ebay or aliexpress with ratings of "10000" (usually actually more like 1000 or less if you bother to actually measure) mAh.

Comment: Google it like I did. You need to demonstrate a degree of self-help and initiative here at SE. This is not just my opinion; it's a rule. Also, bear in mind that this is a design site and questions on what a particular battery supplier might use are generally felt to be off-topic and there are good reasons for that. This isn't a site about commercial devices and their uses except when it comes to analysing their design (in the presence of design data like schematics).

Comment: mAh may be the same but the power bank battery unit has a lower output voltage hence lower Wh.

Comment: @Andyaka I did google it I came across many speculations that say either way. And even hp's official site says they are the same. That's why I asked for your input. A link to where you found the info would suffice if you are not interested in explaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

20,000 mAh capacity as figured in a power bank is about 72 Wh (they calculate it based on a single cell voltage of 3.6 V average).

That's a genuine wh rating on (say) a Huawei or Xiaomi power bank as opposed to some outrageous lie by a nefarious Aliexpress seller. It's quite heavy too, uses good quality 18650 batteries.

Given the usual premium for Apple products, I don't see an inexplicable price difference per Wh.

Comment: so let's say I had a power bank with 10,000mAh and an 11V will it run a laptop without any issues given that the power banks ratings are reliable? Asking this because @Andy aka said the laptop batteries nowadays are not the same as power banks. And googling it I had answers that said they were the same and some say they are not. Couldn't get a definitive answer

Comment: There's no room for an 18650 in those batteries you linked, so clearly they are using another style, just as Andy said. They used to be 18650 almost universally. You have a power bank that outputs 11V? Anyway, 36wh minus a bit for voltage conversion efficiency so at the output connector you'd get maybe 33wh or 3 hours at 1A draw. There is also the world of Li-ion cordless power tool batteries..  I suggest using wh rather than mAh and allowing for converter inefficiency (on good brands) and outrageous lies (on no-name stuff). Weight is also a good indication.

Comment: No, I don't have an 11v power bank just a scenario. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Note: Keep in mind that the prismatic cells and the 18650 cylindrical cells are not radically different in terms of wh per kilogram. They're different but not so different. The former are thinner form factor which allows thinner notebook computers, but the chemistry and internal arrangement is very similar. Also "would it run without any issues" depends on the current draw of the laptop. If the power bank can support only 1A and the laptop tries to draw 2A there will be issues aside from battery *capacity*.